# Django View is not getting processed completely after HttpResponse() call

Tags: python, django, mechanize, httpresponse

I have a view named `Scan` which takes a modelform `input and` sends it to another view `Processscan` which is supposed to be getting the value of the `input` from `Scan` view and process it in `Processscan` view.

Currently, `Processscan` is getting the input from `Scan` view and outputting the value, but isn't going past the line:

```
return HttpResponse("We got to the processor with domain: " + EnteredDomain)
```

**`Process` view looks like:**

```
def Scan(request):
    form = SubmitDomain(request.POST or None) # A form bound to the POST data
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        if form.is_valid(): # If form input passes initial validation...
            domainNmCleaned = form.cleaned_data['domainNm']  ## clean data in dictionary
            form.save() #save cleaned data to the db from dictionary
            try:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/Processscan/?domainNm=' + domainNmCleaned)
            except:
                raise ValidationError(('Invalid request'), code='invalid')    ## [ TODO ]: add a custom error page here.
    else:
        form = SubmitDomain()

    return render(request, 'VA/index.html', {
        'form' : form
    })
```

**`Processscan` view looks like:**

```
def Processscan(request):
    # mechanize setup
    harvest = mechanize.Browser()
    harvest.addheaders = settings.MECHANIZE_USER_AGENT_HARVESTING

    EnteredDomain = request.GET.get('domainNm')
    return HttpResponse("We got to the processor with domain: " + EnteredDomain)

    mechanizeBrowser = mechanize.Browser    
    mechanizeBrowser.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

    r=mechanizeBrowser.open('http://www.thedomain.com')
    output = r.read()
    print output
```

Currently, the output is stopping right here, when it should be continuing in `Processscan`:

```
 return HttpResponse("We got to the processor with domain: " + EnteredDomain)
```

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: You mean it's returning "We got to the..." instead of executing the rest of `Processscan()`?

Comment: How do you expect the process to execute statemetns after the `return` statement ?

Comment: @dan-klasson - yes. It stops at the return HttpResponse() and doesnt continue doing mechanize. Any idea what Im doing wrong?

Comment: `return` is doing just that - returning the `HttpResponse`. The return statement is what's preventing any code after that point from being processed. You need to move the return statement.

Comment: So sorry  for the newbieness - but, anything after HttpResponse on a view is more or less ignored?

Comment: No.. Its not `anything after HttpResponse` - It is `anything after a return statement` is ignored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything after `return HttpResponse` gets ignored as that line causes the view to return a `HttpResponse` object. Which is what Django uses to construct the server reply with.

Just take that line out.

Comment: Thanks for your patience - I think I got it fixed. Much appreciated Dan!